# SQL Server Insert on the last Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, unordered

I have a statement which Inserts a new row to the table in my database, but the new row is added on the first row of the table. I want to add a new row on the end of the table, how would I do this?

```
INSERT INTO myTable(IFACTUURREGELNUMMER, FACTUURNUMMER, REGELNUMMER, KOSTCODE, DOSSIERNUMMER, OMSCHRIJVING, RELATIE, PRIJS, AANTAL, BEDRAG, VALUTA, BTWCODE, BTWBEDRAG)
    VALUES (@INVOICELINENUMBERM, @INVOICENUMBER, @RULENUMBER, @COSTCODE, @CASENUMBER, @DESCRIPTION,@RELATION, @PRICE, @QUANTITY, @AMOUNT, @CURRENCIES, @BTWCODE, @BTWAMOUNT)
```

Comment: There is no "first" or "last" in a table, it's an unordered set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no first or last in a table.

Anyway: You can use `ORDER BY`

```sql
SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY IFACTUURREGELNUMMER DESC
```

You can also have multiple expressions in the `ORDER BY`

```sql
SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY IFACTUURREGELNUMMER DESC, INVOICENUMBER ASC
```

Some Database Managment Systems (DMS) like Oracle or Postgres also allow you to order by `NULLS`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY IFACTUURREGELNUMMER DESC,
                               INVOICENUMBER ASC NULLS LAST
SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY IFACTUURREGELNUMMER DESC, 
                               INVOICENUMBER ASC NULLS FIRST
```